# Boost Asio C++ HTTPS Request not hitting server. No errors

Tags: c++, https, boost-asio

I am trying to hit an endpoint using Boost asio ssl C++. Everything goes fine without any errors. But the request just doesnt hit the server. Following is the code:

```
    string protocol,domain,port,path;
    boost::regex ex("(http|https)://([^/ :]+):?([^/ ]*)(/?[^ #?]*)\\x3f?([^ #]*)#?([^ ]*)");
    boost::cmatch what;
    if(regex_match(url.c_str(), what, ex)) 
    {
    protocol= string(what[1].first, what[1].second);
    domain= string(what[2].first, what[2].second);
    port= string(what[3].first, what[3].second);
    path= string(what[4].first, what[4].second);
    }
    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
    boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none );
    ssl_socket socket(io_service, ctx);
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(domain.c_str(), port.c_str());
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    socket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
    // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.

    socket.set_verify_callback(verify_certificate);
    boost::asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator);
    socket.handshake(ssl_socket::client);
    socket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
    // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
    // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
    // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);

    request_stream << "POST "<<path<<"/ssl HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
    request_stream << "Host:" << domain<<":"<<port << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0";
    request_stream << "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream << "Content-Length: " << json.length() << "\r\n"; 
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";  //NOTE THE Double line feed
    request_stream << json<<"\r\n";

    request_stream << std::cin.rdbuf() << std::flush;
    int a=boost::asio::write(socket, request);


     bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
       {
        /* char subject_name[256];
         X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
         X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
         std::cout << "Verifying:\n" << subject_name << std::endl;*/

         return true;
       }
```

I am using a self signed certificate and I strongly believe that is the problem. But then, I am not getting any handshake errors either. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I am getting the following output:

```
    Connected to: 
    Response: short read
```

Now I am not sure why the connected to part is empty. I debugged and cross checked the fact that host, port and path variables are not empty.

Comment: You can't use `remote_endpoint` on a closed connection. So, store it before you send the request, to be on the safe side and not have to worry about the socket having been closed on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method will fail if `port` is empty.

Also, a line end if missing with the User Agent:

```
request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0\r\n";
```

I tried with

```
std::string url = "https://209.85.203.105:443/";
```

and

```
//std::string url = "https://www.google.com:443/";
```

And it works.

### Full Demo

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using ssl_socket = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;

bool verify_certificate(bool /*preverified*/, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& /*ctx*/)
{
    /* char subject_name[256];
       X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
       X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
       std::cout << "Verifying:\n" << subject_name << std::endl;*/

    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::string url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com:443/";
    //std::string url = "https://209.85.203.105:443/";
    std::string json = "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }";

    std::string protocol,domain,port,path;
    boost::regex ex("(http|https)://([^/ :]+):?([^/ ]*)(/?[^ #?]*)\\x3f?([^ #]*)#?([^ ]*)");
    boost::cmatch what;
    if(regex_match(url.c_str(), what, ex)) 
    {
        protocol= std::string(what[1].first, what[1].second);
        domain= std::string(what[2].first, what[2].second);
        port= std::string(what[3].first, what[3].second);
        path= std::string(what[4].first, what[4].second);
    }

    std::cout << "protocol: " << protocol << "\n";
    std::cout << "domain:   " << domain   << "\n";
    std::cout << "port:     " << port     << "\n";
    std::cout << "path:     " << path     << "\n";

    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);

    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds | boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);

    ssl_socket socket(io_service, ctx);

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(domain.c_str(), port.c_str());
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    socket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
    // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.

    socket.set_verify_callback(verify_certificate);
    std::cout << "Connecting... " << std::flush;
    boost::asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator);
    std::cout << "Connected to " << socket.lowest_layer().remote_endpoint() << "\n";
    socket.handshake(ssl_socket::client);
    socket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

    // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
    // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
    // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);

    request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request_stream << "Host:" << domain << ":" << port << "\r\n";
    //request_stream << "Host:" << domain << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0\r\n";
    //request_stream << "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    //request_stream << "Content-Length: " << json.length() << "\r\n"; 
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    //request_stream << json << "\r\n";
    //request_stream << std::cin.rdbuf() << std::flush;

    int a = boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    std::cout << a << " byte sent\n";
    std::vector<char> response(10 * 1024);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto bytes_received = boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(response), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ec);
    response.resize(a);

    std::cout << "Response: " << ec.message() << "\n----------------\n";
    std::cout.write(response.data(), bytes_received) << std::flush;
}
```

Prints

```
protocol: https
domain:   www.stackoverflow.com
port:     443
path:     /
Connecting... Connected to 151.101.129.69:443
101 byte sent
Response: End of file
----------------
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/
Content-Length: 148
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2016 07:13:08 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-ams4420-AMS
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1473318788.479431,VS0,VE342
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=90860619-8a76-9233-21d1-43de9920a25c; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/">here</a></body>
```

Comment: Stack overflow uses a certificate that is issued by a CA and my server doesnt. I believe that is the problem, but then I dont see any errors popping up either.

Comment: That's all very interesting, but I'd prefer if you actually _tested_ instead of repeating your assumptions. (If you did, why not tell us?)

Comment: I did test and it works for servers with certificates issued by CA. In my case, I am using a self signed certificate. The server I am using is a NodeJS server and it doesn't even show a request hitting it.

Comment: So, you need to work out why your verify function is not functioning as expected. That's a different question already, you're getting closer to the goal. There are bound to be a dozen existing questions about this (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bboost-asio%5D+verify_certificate+self-signed or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bboost-asio%5D+verify_certificate e.g.)

Comment: I have added one more observation. I am a noob with this and your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Short read is normal in many circumstances. You don't show the receiving code at all, so I can't tell but if you just keep reading until the connection is closed, then, for sure, that last read will likely be a short read. Read here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html

Comment: Also, SO has many answers on this: https://www.google.nl/search?q=short%20read%20asio%20ssl